# Python numpy, skip columns & read csv file

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a CSV file with 20 columns & about 60000 rows.

I'd like to read fields 2 to 20  only. I've tried the below code but the browser(using ipython) freezes & it just goes n for ages

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

myFile = 'sampleData.csv'
myData = genfromtxt(myFile, delimiter=',', usecols(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
print myData
```

How could I tweak this to work better & actually produce output please?

Comment: I'd think the reading is fast, it's the printing that takes the time. Time just the read. Then print only what you need. Try myData[:10] etc.     Do you have missing values, are you getting error messages?

Comment: genfromtxt() is notoriously slow.  Try loadtxt() which is marginally faster or read it as a pandas dataframe which is [apparently much faster](http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt/). You can use the [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

myFile = 'sampleData.csv'
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(myFile,skiprows=1)) // Skipping header

print df
```

This works like a charm